# I created a Python timer using classes, but it's not running. Where is the problem in code?

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

I wrote this code without using classes and the timer works fine. But here it seems to stop at 00:00:01. Where is the error in the code preventing it from running? My guess is in:

```
update_time = self.stopwatch.after(1000, self.update)
```

But I'm not sure.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyGUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('Timer with classes')

        running = False
        hours, minutes, seconds = 0, 0, 0


        self.stopwatch = tk.Label(self.root, text='00:00:00', width=25, font=('Arial', 30), justify='center')
        self.stopwatch.pack()

        self.button_start = tk.Button(self.root, text="START TIMER", width=25, borderwidth=5, command=self.start, font=('Arial', 30))
        self.button_start.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()


    def update(self):
        hours, minutes, seconds = 0,0,0
        seconds += 1
        if seconds == 60:
            minutes += 1
            seconds = 0
        if minutes == 60:
            hours += 1
            minutes = 0
        hours_string = f'{hours}' if hours > 9 else f'0{hours}'
        minutes_string = f'{minutes}' if minutes > 9 else f'0{minutes}'
        seconds_string = f'{seconds}' if seconds > 9 else f'0{seconds}'
        self.stopwatch.config(text=hours_string + ':' + minutes_string + ':' + seconds_string)
        global update_time
        update_time = self.stopwatch.after(1000, self.update)

    def start(self):
        running=False
        if not running:
            self.update()
            running = True



MyGUI()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your timer works, however, it only displays one second because you initialize your seconds, minutes and hours in your update method. What you want to do instead is to declare `hours, minutes, seconds` as instance attributes of your class so you can initialize them on startup in your `start(self)` and increment in your `update(self)` methods like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyGUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('Timer with classes')

        self.running = False
        self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds = 0, 0, 0


        self.stopwatch = tk.Label(self.root, text='00:00:00', width=25, font=('Arial', 30), justify='center')
        self.stopwatch.pack()

        self.button_start = tk.Button(self.root, text="START TIMER", width=25, borderwidth=5, command=self.start, font=('Arial', 30))
        self.button_start.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()


    def update(self):
        self.seconds += 1
        if self.seconds == 60:
            self.minutes += 1
            self.seconds = 0
        if self.minutes == 60:
            self.hours += 1
            self.minutes = 0
        hours_string = f'{self.hours}' if self.hours > 9 else f'0{self.hours}'
        minutes_string = f'{self.minutes}' if self.minutes > 9 else f'0{self.minutes}'
        seconds_string = f'{self.seconds}' if self.seconds > 9 else f'0{self.seconds}'
        self.stopwatch.config(text=hours_string + ':' + minutes_string + ':' + seconds_string)
        global update_time
        update_time = self.stopwatch.after(1000, self.update)

    def start(self):
        self.running=False
        if not self.running:
            self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds = 0,0,0
            self.update()
            running = True



MyGUI()
```

Comment: This correctly diagnoses the issue. The only quibble I have with it is the use of the term "class variable" which typically describes class attributes, declared at class scope, not instance attributes that are assigned to a specific instance (via `self`).

Comment: Totally valid quibble :) edited my answer, thanks!